# Exponential function in android

Tags: java, android, double

How yto convert a value to exponential i mean

```
1.522222 to 152.2222e-2 and   .1522222e+1 and 2

2. string s=123456789123
```

my s.length is greater than 9 than i have to get a value 1.234567891e+11 and the same in case 
0.0123466789, now i  need out put like 1.23456789e-2

Comment: hey, by default i'm getting the value converted to exponential but only to 6 places. for ex my output before i kept the function was
6.5851382366E21
and after i have used your function it became 6.585138E21.
I need a conversion like, when the length of my string is more than 9 make it to exponential value.
provide me solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public static String fromStandartToExponent(String v){
    return String.format("%e",Double.parseDouble(v));
}
```

See java doc for `java.util.Formatter` for more formatting options